# setting up networking on centos6 virtualbox guest with xp host

Tags: networking, windows-xp, centos, virtualbox

I'm using virtualbox and trying to get my centos6 virtual machine onto the network. Virtualbox is running on XP. In the virtual box settings I've enabled network adapter 1, selected the bridged adapter and selected the default hardware. On the virtual machine I've edited configuration files as follows (making sure that the mac address / hardware address matches the adapters mac address from the virutalbox settings):

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcofg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="none
MACADDR="08:00:27:7D:A8:DC"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=10.0.20.10
GATEWAY=255.0.0.55
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=dev.host.com
NETOWRKING_IPV6=no
GATEWAY=10.0.0.55
# cat /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=08:00:27:7D:A8:DC
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
IPADDR=10.0.20.10
GATEWAY=10.0.0.55
TYPE=Ethernet
```

When i restart networking I get the following:

```
# /etc/init.d/network restart
Shutting down loopback interface:
Bringing up loopback interface:
Bringing up interface eth0: Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
```

eth0 never comes up and obviously I've got no access to / from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/ that was associating an old mac address from the cloned machine with eth0. I edited the rule (/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistant-net.rules), to use the new mac address virtualbox generated when I enabled the network adapter.

eth0 is up and running - I can access the network. (thanks to the centos forum).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this behavior in other Cent OS version or Linux distros but in Cent OS 6.1, /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistant-net.rules is automatically generated by the OS and after a couple of reboots, it will be regenerated based on the Mac Addresses in the ifcfg-eth* files.

So I didn't have to edit the file. I just had to reboot the VM a 1-2 more times.

Answer (score 0):

> Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.

This is quite a generic error for a number of issues.  UDEV can work often however renaming the NIC itself among other solutions such as specifying the HW address will work too.  But that's not all of them.  Give this older post a try.  Looks like a collection for a bunch of solutions to this error:

[Device eth0 does not seem to be present](http://microdevsys.com/wp/device-eth0-does-not-seem-to-be-present-delaying-initialization-linux-networking/)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Always check the file format of ifcfg-ethX was not modified by a Windows editor. In case the line ends are in windows format, you will encounter the same problem.
This cause is hard to notice and the error message is misleading.